# How to duplicate cell data in excel between rows if the cells are empty when another cell matches

Tags: vba, excel

I know the title is really long winded, I will try to explain

I am trying to get Magento products into Zen Cart (background only - shouldn't be relevant).

I have an excel 2010 xls spreadsheet and in it I have a load of product data: skus, prices, categories, etc... you get the idea. I have each of the products along with their data listed once, each with a unique SKU field.

But... Some of these products are in more than one category and the way I am importing, each product needs to be listed multiple times, once for each category.

So, I have done an sql dump which contains two columns; sku and category. I have pasted these values into excel as new rows, so now I have a situation like this (with a lot more entries):

[image]

As you can see for each sku (left highlight) there is one entry containing all the data apart from the category (right highlight) and then there is an additional entry for each category it belongs to which contains only the category and sku but none of the other data.

So, what I need to do is some how copy all the data (apart from the categories column) across all cells with the same sku. Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this without hitting Ctrl+V several hundred times. I realise VBA can probably handle this pretty easily, but I dont have a clue on that front.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you’re willing to use a second sheet, and to reference the data rather than actually copying.

On Sheet2, set `A1` to `=IF(Sheet1!A1="", "", Sheet1!A1)`.  Drag (extend/fill) this down to `A500` (as much data as you have on Sheet1, or further, to allow for growth).  Also drag `A1` over to `AA1` and then drag that down to `AA500`.

Then set `B2` to `=IF($AA2="", Sheet1!B2, B1)`, drag it to `Z2`, and drag `B2:Z2` down to `B500:Z500`.

P.S. If any of your data (columns) are dates, you will probably need to explicitly format them as dates on Sheet2.  Ditto for any other values that are formatted any non-default way (e.g., Currency or Percentage).  It may be necessary to do this *only* to cells that have values in them (and not blank cells).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm gonna take a crack at it now.

Comment: You are a superstar, works great. One little problem I'm having is that my dates in the original sheet [dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss] are being displayed as five digit integers, e.g. [21/01/2012 00:00:00] becomes [40929]. applying custom formatting doesn't help. Any ideas what is causing this, how to fix it. C&P job otherwise.

Comment: That’s odd; applying formatting works for me.  You are doing it to all the affected cells on Sheet2, right?

Comment: Do you know what, my bad. It does work! I had selected the entire column and some of the cells were empty. It only works if you only apply it only to cells with datetimes in. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need VBA, unless you need to do this many times.
Assuming the sheet with your data is called `Source` and the sheet with the result is called `Dest`, you can get what you want following these steps on the sheet `Dest`:

- On A1 type `=Source!A1`
- On A2 type `=IF(ISBLANK(Source!A2),A1,Source!A2)`
- Select the range A1:XX1 (where XX is the last column of the sheet Source)
- Press Ctrl+R (to copy the first cell to the right)
- Select the range A2:XX## (where ## is the last row of the sheet Source)
- Press Ctrl+R and Ctrl+D (to copy to the right and down)

Here is an explanation of what's going on:
The first row is copied from the Source as it is.
Each cell of the second row is copied from Source only if that cell is empty, otherwise the cell above is copied.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the quick and dirty solution:

1. Select the columns you need to be filled
2. Press Goto `Ctrl-G`
3. Special `Alt-S'
4. Blanks (`Alt-K`, `Enter`)
5. This should select all blank cells. Now type  `=B2` (assuming you're in B3, i.e. use the cell above the active cell) Important: Press `Ctrl-Enter` instead of Enter to enter the formula.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

On a new Worksheet get the numbers 1-26 running across the top in Row1 by typing 1 in cell A1, 2 in cell A2, and then selecting those two cells and filling through Z.

Now in A2 type the following formula `=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A1,Sheet1!$A:$AA,VALUE(A$1),FALSE)`
Fill this formula in the Range A2:Z## (where ## represents your last row of data).
Then copy Row1 from Sheet1 to Row1 on Sheet2.

This formula will copy the rows of data straight down into the empty rows below them (assuming the sku only changes where there is a row of new information.

This will then all be active formulas, so I would recommend selecting all on Sheet2 and right-clicking in cell A1, and paste special by value.